# changing from template to normal data types (int,float,...etc)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I had to make a group project. Its idea is to make all mathematical properties on two matrices (add, multiply, transpose, subtract), but we had to use templates and vectors.

My problem/concern is, if it was going to be implemented not with vectors or templates, how can I do such thing?

For example, this part:

```
//Matrix is the class name,mtrx is a private vector in the class
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T>& obj){
    Matrix<T> res(*this);
    int r1,c1,r2,c2;
    r1 = mtrx.size();
    c1 = mtrx[0].size();
    r2 = obj.mtrx.size();
    c2 = obj.mtrx[0].size();
    if(r1==r2 && c1==c2){
        for(int i = 0; i < r1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < c1; j++){
                res.mtrx[i][j] += obj.mtrx[i][j];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    throw invalid_argument("Cannot add, matrices don't have same dimensions");
}
```

Comment: > "My problem/concern is, if it was going to be implemented not with vectors or templates, how can I do such thing?"

you don't. In weaker languages without generics you would have to duplicate your code for each type: `void add_matrix_int(matrix_int* lhs, matrix_int* rhs, matrix_int** res);` `void add_matrix_float(matrix_float* lhs, matrix_float* rhs, matrix_** res);` for instance in C89

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have a small inquiry here by the lhs and the rhs you mean like the first and second matrix? @Jean-MichaëlCelerier

Comment: Yes -- it's short-hand for left-hand side and right-hand side, referring to what you would write: `matrixA + matrixB;`